# ElasticSearch: facet for price dependent on date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a database of services with prices and I want to search on service name and show facet with price ranges and counts. Searching on such database would be simple, nevertheless the price is dependent on date and thus can fluctuate.

---

Service 1 | 1.1.-15.2. $50 | 16.2.-10.5. $80 | 11.5.-20.7. $90

Service 2 | 1.1.-14.2. $60 | 15.2.-11.5. $90 | 12.5.-21.7. $80

Service 3 | 1.1.-18.2. $70 | 19.2.-17.5. $50 | 18.5.-25.7. $70

---

I would like to provide a search based on **name** and **date range** when user is looking for a service:

*Filter example:* 'car washing' between 1.2. - 15.3.

**RESULT**

*Display*: services with given text that are provided in the given date range

*Facet Price group*: $0-$50 (23), $50-$100 (14), $100-$150 (5)
- number of services within price bucket

**REMARKS**
I believe this is easy when price would be static, but I find it hard when it is dependent on provided date range. For example how to deal when user defines a date range that overlaps 2 different prices of a matched service? Can ElasticSearch take the lowest price for example? How to deal with such case in ES?

Comment: To be certain I understand the structure, there are multiple services (eg. carwash?) with multiple dates and prices. You want to be able to search for search name filtered by a date range? The only thing I find confusing is the date changing the price, how is this happening, and is Elasticsearch being used as the datastore for this?

Comment: Yes you are right - multiple services where each service has different price based on date. And user can search for service in a specific interval. So the price then should be the lowest price in that period.

One way could be to generate each service multiple times for each price period, but then search could return each service multiple times and I am not sure if it is easy to deduplicate such result in ES.

I do not use ES as datastore, only indexing. But if it would be necessary, I guess the price could be stored.